# Extract part of number inside parenthesis in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to extract 54 from (38/54).

```
xp <- posta %>%
 html_nodes(".percent-on:nth-child(5) .match-stats-number-left .stat-
 breakdown") %>%
 html_text() %>%
 gsub("[^0-9.-]", "",.) %>%
 as.numeric()
```

With the above I get 3854. I then tried with:

```
str_extract(., '\\d+') %>%
```

This gives me 38. I can't figure out how to extract only 54.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str_extract_all` and choose the second one:

```
tx <- "(38/54)"
str_extract_all(tx,"\\d+",TRUE)[2]
[1] "54"
```

Comment: Thank you but I get error for incorrect number of dimensions. When I use your code with pipes should it not be?: "str_extract_all(.,"\\d+",TRUE) [2] %>%"

Comment: Looks like you have to do the subsetting in a separate pipe: `tx %>% str_extract_all("\\d+",TRUE) %>% .[2]`